# Why does IP address change when you switch on airplane mode for 4G smartphones?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I am curious why airplane mode changes the IP address and whether airplane mode on a regular laptop would also change the IP address.

Comment: Does my answer seems to be sufficient ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about Airplane Mode on a mobile device.

I don't think, that toggling airplane mode will inevitably change the IP address. It depends on your provider.

If you turn on airplane mode, the mobile device is disconnected from your providers base stations. Turning it off again causes the device to re-login to your providers base station, which can possibly lead to a new IP address, because you appear like a new subscriber.

Turning on airplane mode on a regular laptop can also lead to a new IP address. If your laptop is using a cell connection (SIM card) it is the same like with an cell phone.

If your Laptop is using a wi-fi connection, you may have the same IP address, depending on your ISPs router configuration.